# Session Affinity Settings for multiple Pods exposed by a single service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

I have a setup Metallb as LB with Nginx Ingress installed on K8S cluster.
I have read about session affinity and its significance but so far I do not have a clear picture.

How can I create a single service exposing multiple pods of the same application?
After creating the single service entry point, how to map the specific client IP to Pod abstracted by the service?

Is there any blog explaining this concept in terms of how the mapping between Client IP and POD is done in kubernetes?

But I do not see Client's IP in the YAML. Then, How is this service going to map the traffic to respective clients to its endpoints? this is the question I have.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  sessionAffinityConfig:
    clientIP:
      timeoutSeconds: 10000
```

Comment: because, you are using nginx as ingress controller, We are talking about http sessions, that means, you need to setup cookies stickiness in your ingress rules, if you go in the github repo of the nginx ingress controller, you have a lot of examples

Comment: @c4f4t0r I want to use normal session affinity before going to cookies based. also, I want to validate and see if the Client request is mapped to the Pod based on its IP.

Comment: if you have web application doing stickness based on the ip is not so good, if you have a mobile user, the ip can changes many times

Comment: I am trying to validate this feature first. you are right in case of web application using sticky sessions is useful. and that is a more advanced part of session control I would say. I think I need to learn basic mapping first.

Answer (score 9):

Main concept of Session Affinity is to redirect traffic from one client always to specific node. Please keep in mind that session affinity is a **best-effort** method and there are scenarios where it will fail due to pod restarts or network errors.
There are two main types of Session Affinity:

**1)** *Based on Client IP*

This option works well for scenario where there is only one client per IP. In this method you don't need Ingress/Proxy between K8s services and client. 
Client IP should be static, because each time when client will change IP he will be redirected to another pod.

To enable the session affinity in kubernetes, we can add the following to the service definition.

```
service.spec.sessionAffinity: ClientIP
```

Because community provided proper manifest to use this method I will not duplicate.

**2)** *Based on Cookies*

It works when there are multiple clients from the same IP, because it´s stored at web browser level. This method require Ingress object. Steps to apply this method with more detailed information can be found [here](https://medium.com/@diegomrtnzg/redirect-your-users-to-the-same-pod-by-using-session-affinity-on-kubernetes-baebf6a1733b) under **Session affinity based on Cookie** section.

- Create NGINX controller deployment
- Create NGINX service
- Create Ingress
- Redirect your public DNS name to the NGINX service public/external IP.

> About mapping ClientIP and POD, according to [Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#virtual-ips-and-service-proxies)
>   kube-proxy is responsible for SessionAffinity. One of Kube-Proxy job
>   is writing to IPtables, more details [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#is-the-kube-proxy-working) so thats how it is
>   mapped.

Articles which might help with understanding Session Affinity:
https://sookocheff.com/post/kubernetes/building-stateful-services/
https://medium.com/@diegomrtnzg/redirect-your-users-to-the-same-pod-by-using-session-affinity-on-kubernetes-baebf6a1733b

Answer (score 1):

follow the service reference for session affinity

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  sessionAffinityConfig:
    clientIP:
      timeoutSeconds: 10000
```

Comment: Yes, so far I have seen this YAML used as an example everywhere. But I do not see Client's IP in the YAML. How is this service going to map the traffic to respective clients to its endpoints? this is the question I have.

Comment: sessionAffinity: ClientIP

Comment: the above property would route the traffic to same backend pod based on clientIP

Comment: do we need to make any changes in Ingress file ? or service file alone enough for above sticky session configuration.

Comment: yes, you might need to enable nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity